# Feature file is pointing to a non-existing project

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am writing a Cucumber-TestNG- Selenium framework for my application. I am able to execute test cases from my Runner class but when I try to do that same through the feature file, I get an error that it is pointing to some project which is non-existent.
[image]

Above is the snapshot of the Run As Configuration properties of the feature file and there is an error in the classpath.

When I deleted this file and created a new one, I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath:
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parseAssumeClasspathScheme(GluePath.java:54)
    at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parse(GluePath.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:160)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:107)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:100)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:96)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:131)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:127)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:22)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3057)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
    ... 10 more
```

I am able to execute the test cases through testng.xml and Cucumber Runner file.

Please let me know how to resolve this error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Was Also Getting Same Error. If You Are Using Cucumber v4.2.3. Use v4.2.2 And Try. For Me It Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Cucumber Feature Runner tab and then check the following three fields are set accordingly.

1. Project,
2. Feature Path,
3. Glue

if you set all correctly, it should execute without any error.

Comment: Done with the settings. Added the snapshot of the same in the question above.If I execute with the above settings, I am getting following error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported scheme: C:/Users/212743214/EclipseWorkspaceVA/CC/src/test/java/features/Administration/ExportDatabase.feature
 at cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader.resources(MultiLoader.java:28)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.loadFromFeaturePath(FeatureLoader.java:41)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:35)

Comment: I guess, the project class path is not set. please set it and try again.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that or how to check that. Could u please explain that or share a relevant link.

Comment: Go to build path and set the class path

Comment: Do u mean to say  should go to the source tab of the Java Build path and Link Source?

Comment: make sure your project folders are in source

Comment: That's there, I guess. Can u check the snapshot in the question?

Comment: add test folder as well into source. src/test/java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188723/discussion-between-neha-and-murthi).

Comment: can u continue this discussion in chat